How to fill and submit login pop-up in JavaScript for Web Extension
I'm trying to develop a web extension that does a couple of things for a particular program. But in order to access some pages I need to submit a username and password in the form of a pop-up akin to a router. The kind before the webpage loads. Is there a method to do this in JavaScript that can be done without opening a a window or new tab? This is being developed in chromium

I've tried to research methods on how to submit the forms, but all I've come across are methods on producing the pop-up. The ones that seem to work here use Ajax but I also wanted to know if it is possible for my conditions and can use the fetch() API.
